# Dependent survey questions in R shinysurveys: matrix questions

Tags: r, shiny, survey

I am currently trying to create a survey in R using the shinysurveys package. My goal is to create dependent matrix questions (e.g. Likert scale). As long as I don't use matrix questions everything is fine. However, by using the code below, R returns an error message and the second, dependent question doesn't appear.

To clarify, I want the second question to show up, only if the first question is answered with "1".

Would be great, if someone could help me out :)

```
df_1 <- data.frame(question = rep("A", 7),
                   option = rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "I don't know"), 1),
                   input_type = rep("matrix", 7),
                   input_id = rep("ID1", 7),
                   dependence = NA,
                   dependence_value = NA,
                   required = TRUE
)


df_2 <- data.frame(question = c(rep("B", 7)),
                   option = rep(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "I don't know"), 1),
                   input_type = rep("matrix", 7),
                   input_id = rep("ID2", 7),
                   dependence = rep("ID1", 7),
                   dependence_value = rep("1", 7),
                   required = TRUE
)

df_merged <- rbind(df_1, df_2)

#create user interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  surveyOutput(df = df_merged,
               survey_title = "Title",
               survey_description = "Description"))


#specify server function
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  renderSurvey()

  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Survey End!"
    ))
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```